# Name of the process with highest cpu usage

Tags: windows, performance, operating-system

I have a [Samurize](http://www.samurize.com/modules/news/) config that shows a CPU usage graph similar to Task manager.

How do I also display the name of the process with the current highest CPU usage percentage?

I would like this to be updated, at most, once per second.  Samurize can call a command line tool and display it's output on screen, so this could also be an option.

---

Further clarification:

I have investigated writing my own command line c# .NET application to enumerate the array returned from System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses(), but the Process instance class does not seem to include a CPU percentage property.

Can I calculate this in some way?

Comment: Is this a question about how to use the samurize package?  Perhaps you could rephrase as a programming question?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

With PowerShell:

```
Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object -first 3 | Format-Table CPU,ProcessName -hidetableheader
```

returns somewhat like:

```
  16.8641632 System
   12.548072 csrss
  11.9892168 powershell
```

Comment: also, clearly, CPU doesn't give you percent of cpu used. it's the total processor time in seconds that process has been active. powershell "get-process | get-member | Select-Object Name,Definition | sort-object Name | format-list" CPU is defined as  {get=$this.TotalProcessorTime.TotalSeconds;}

Answer (score 6):

What you want to get its the instant CPU usage (kind of)...

Actually, the instant CPU usage for a process does not exists. Instead you have to make two measurements and calculate the average CPU usage, the formula is quite simple:

> AvgCpuUsed = [TotalCPUTime(process,time2) - TotalCPUTime(process,time1)] / [time2-time1]

The lower Time2 and Time1 difference is, the more "instant" your measurement will be. Windows Task Manager calculate the CPU use with an interval of one second. I've found that is more than enough and you might even consider doing it in 5 seconds intervals cause the act of measuring itself takes up CPU cycles...

So, first, to get the average CPU time

```
    using System.Diagnostics;

float GetAverageCPULoad(int procID, DateTme from, DateTime, to)
{
  // For the current process
  //Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
  // Or for any other process given its id
  Process proc = Process.GetProcessById(procID);
  System.TimeSpan lifeInterval = (to - from);
  // Get the CPU use
  float CPULoad = (proc.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds / lifeInterval.TotalMilliseconds) * 100;
  // You need to take the number of present cores into account
  return CPULoad / System.Environment.ProcessorCount;
}
```

now, for the "instant" CPU load you'll need an specialized class:

```
 class ProcLoad
{
  // Last time you checked for a process
  public Dictionary<int, DateTime> lastCheckedDict = new Dictionary<int, DateTime>();

  public float GetCPULoad(int procID)
  {
    if (lastCheckedDict.ContainsKey(procID))
    {
      DateTime last = lastCheckedDict[procID];
      lastCheckedDict[procID] = DateTime.Now;
      return GetAverageCPULoad(procID, last, lastCheckedDict[procID]);
    }
    else
    {
      lastCheckedDict.Add(procID, DateTime.Now);
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

You should call that class from a timer (or whatever interval method you like) for **each process you want to monitor**, if you want all the processes just use the [Process.GetProcesses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9.aspx) static method

Answer (score 2):

Building on Frederic's answer and utilizing the code at the bottom of the page [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/07/13/join-object.aspx) (for an example of usage see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/10/04/joining-multiple-tables-grouping-and-evaluating-totals.aspx) post) to join the full set of processes gotten from `Get-Process`, we get the following:

```
$sampleInterval = 3

$process1 = Get-Process |select Name,Id, @{Name="Sample1CPU"; Expression = {$_.CPU}}

Start-Sleep -Seconds $sampleInterval

$process2 = Get-Process | select Id, @{Name="Sample2CPU"; Expression = {$_.CPU}}

$samples = Join-Object -Left $process1 -Right $process2 -LeftProperties Name,Sample1CPU -RightProperties Sample2CPU -Where {$args[0].Id -eq $args[1].Id}

$samples | select Name,@{Name="CPU Usage";Expression = {($_.Sample2CPU-$_.Sample1CPU)/$sampleInterval * 100}} | sort -Property "CPU Usage" -Descending | select -First 10 | ft -AutoSize
```

Which gives an example output of

```
Name                  CPU Usage
----                  ---------
firefox        20.8333333333333
powershell_ise 5.72916666666667
Battle.net               1.5625
Skype                    1.5625
chrome                   1.5625
chrome         1.04166666666667
chrome         1.04166666666667
chrome         1.04166666666667
chrome         1.04166666666667
LCore          1.04166666666667
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use [Pmon.exe](http://commandwindows.com/server2003tools.htm) for this. You can get it as part of the [Windows Resource Kit tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd) (the link is to the Server 2003 version, which can apparently be used in XP as well).

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.TotalProcessorTime
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.totalprocessortime.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Somehow

`Get-Process | Sort-Object CPU -desc | Select-Object -first 3 | Format-Table CPU,ProcessName,TotalProcessorTime -hidetableheader`

wasn't getting the CPU information from the remote machine. I had to come up with this.

`Get-Counter '\Process(*)\% Processor Time' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples | Select-Object -Property instancename, cookedvalue| Sort-Object -Property cookedvalue -Descending| Select-Object -First 10| ft -AutoSize`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the formula, Jorge.  I don't quite understand why you have to divide by the number of cores, but the numbers I get match the Task Manager. Here's my powershell code:

```
$procID = 4321

$time1 = Get-Date
$cpuTime1 = Get-Process -Id $procID | Select -Property CPU

Start-Sleep -s 2

$time2 = Get-Date
$cpuTime2 = Get-Process -Id $procID | Select -Property CPU

$avgCPUUtil = ($cpuTime2.CPU - $cpuTime1.CPU)/($time2-$time1).TotalSeconds *100 / [System.Environment]::ProcessorCount
```

Comment: Thanks for the working example! Finally realized that the CPU property was the TotalSeconds of the TotalProcessorTime for the process and that TotalSeconds is only available as a TimeSpan object and not a DateTime object.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it  this way :-

```
public Process getProcessWithMaxCPUUsage()
    {
        const int delay = 500;
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

        var counters = new List<PerformanceCounter>();

        foreach (Process process in processes)
        {
            var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", process.ProcessName);
            counter.NextValue();
            counters.Add(counter);
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(delay);
        //You must wait(ms) to ensure that the current
        //application process does not have MAX CPU
        int mxproc = -1;
        double mxcpu = double.MinValue, tmpcpu;
        for (int ik = 0; ik < counters.Count; ik++)
        {
            tmpcpu = Math.Round(counters[ik].NextValue(), 1);
            if (tmpcpu > mxcpu)
            {
                mxcpu = tmpcpu;
                mxproc = ik;
            }

        }
        return processes[mxproc];
    }
```

Usage:-

```
static void Main()
    {
        Process mxp=getProcessWithMaxCPUUsage();
        Console.WriteLine(mxp.ProcessName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar riff on some other answers without requiring extra commands like join-object. 6 seconds seems more accurate.  Was testing with sysinternals cpustres and task manager.  Don't just save the process object, because the cpu property keeps updating.

```
# top.ps1

param($amount = 5)

$sleeptime = 6
$numcores = Get-WmiObject Win32_processor | % NumberOfCores

# keep cpu from changing
$ps1 = ps | select name,cpu,id
sleep $sleeptime
$ps2 = ps | select name,cpu,id

$ps1 | % { $ps1hash = @{} } { $ps1hash[$_.id] = $_ }

$ps2 | % {
  $ps2item = $_
  [pscustomobject]@{
    name = $ps2item.name
    percentCpu = ( $ps2item.cpu - $ps1hash[$ps2item.id].cpu ) / $sleeptime / 
      $numcores * 100 | % tostring 0.## | % { [double]$_ }
    id = $ps2item.id
  }
} | sort -desc percentCpu | select -first $amount
```

```
.\top 5

name           percentCpu    id
----           ----------    --
CPUSTRES64          31.64  7504
steamwebhelper       3.64 17512
powershell           2.21  4836
steamwebhelper       0.99 14464
Taskmgr              0.78  9948
```